# Change select options based on another selected option

Tags: javascript, html

When I select an option from semester than it should open subjects from that semester and not anywhere else 2 different option box for semester and subjects

```html
<select class="form-select" id="sem" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" required>
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option value="Sem1">Sem1</option>
        <option value="Sem2">Sem2</option>
        <option value="Sem3">Sem3</option>
        <option value="Sem4">Sem4</option>
        <option value="Sem5">Sem5</option>
        <option value="Sem6">Sem6</option>
        <option value="Sem7">Sem7</option>
        <option value="Sem8">Sem8</option>
      </select>
      <label for="inputGroupSelect01">Semester</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md">
  <div class="form-floating">
    <select class="form-select" id="Sub1" required>
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option value="sub1">Applied Maths-1</option>
      <option value="sub2">Applied Physics-1</option>
      <option value="sub3">Applied Physics-2</option>

    </select>
    <label for="inputGroupSelect01">Subject Name</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if i understand you perfectly, but do you want something like this?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">

   </head>
  <body>
    <select class="form-select" id="sem" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" required>
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option value="Sem1">Sem1</option>
      <option value="Sem2">Sem2</option>
      <option value="Sem3">Sem3</option>
    </select>
    <label for="inputGroupSelect01">Semester</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md">
<div  class="form-floating">
  <select id="genDropdown" class="form-select" id="Sub1" required>
    <option  selected>Choose a sem...</option>

  </select>
  <label for="inputGroupSelect01">Subject Name</label>
  <script>
    function doHTML(list){
      let string ="";
      let index = 0;
      list.forEach(element => {
        string += `<option value="sub${index}">${element}</option>`;
        
      });
      return string;
    }
    function dynamicdropdown(sem){
      let subjects1 = ["Applied Maths-1", "Applied Physics-1"];
      let subjects2 = ["Applied Maths-2", "Applied Physics-2"];
      let subjects3 = ["Applied Maths-3", "Applied Physics-3"];
      let genDropdown = document.getElementById("genDropdown");
      if(sem=="Sem1"){
        genDropdown.innerHTML = doHTML(subjects1);
      }
      if(sem=="Sem2"){
        genDropdown.innerHTML = doHTML(subjects2);
      }
      if(sem=="Sem3"){
        genDropdown.innerHTML = doHTML(subjects3);
      }

    }
  </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Hope that could help you!

Comment: yaa it works but can you help me explain your script...am new to javascript so most things present in script wen overhead... thanks

Comment: Of course @LuciferM, the function `doHTML` gets an array and goes through it with a forEach building a string with text html, if the function gets [a, b] return "<option value="sub0">a</option><option value="sub1">b</option>".

Comment: And then you need to define an element in the code HTML to get the element in JavaScript (in my case is the one with the id genDropdown), i took it with `document.getElementById("genDropdown")` and in depending on the input (the first dropdown), you assign one text html or other, with the property "innerHTML" (this property put inside the element in the HTML the string)

Comment: @LuciferM, If you are still in doubt, you can follow asking. And sorry if my English isn't the best. :)

Comment: Thanks i understood this is good for 2 option,what if i want to connect 3 dropdowns i.e. if i select a sem then next dropdown should give option of subjects from that sem, after selecting the subject from that sem the next dropw down should give chapters related to that subject selected

Comment: you need to define another html element like the one with "genDropdown" (with another id) and in the element of genDropdown define a new "on change" like in the first select and repeat the process with the new element, i think that you can use the same function `doHTML`, @LuciferM

Answer (score 1):

you need to use javascript to define the dropdown content,
check this snippet about how to clear old options and add new options related to your selection

you can either append the new options as childs to the dropdownlist

```js
function dynamicdropdown(n) {
var arr1 = ["sem1 options","sem1 options","sem1 options","sem1 options","sem1 options"];
var arr2 = ["sem2 options","sem2 options","sem2 options","sem2 options","sem2 options"];
if (n === "Sem1") {
document.getElementById('Sub1').innerHTML = '';
for (var i =0; i< arr1.length; i++) {
document.getElementById('Sub1').innerHTML += "<option>" + arr1[i] + "</option>";
}
} else if (n === "Sem2") {
document.getElementById('Sub1').innerHTML = '';
for (var i =0; i< arr2.length; i++) {
document.getElementById('Sub1').innerHTML += "<option>" + arr2[i] + "</option>";
}
}
}
```

```html
<select class="form-select" id="sem" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" required>
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option value="Sem1">Sem1</option>
        <option value="Sem2">Sem2</option>
        <option value="Sem3">Sem3</option>
        <option value="Sem4">Sem4</option>
        <option value="Sem5">Sem5</option>
        <option value="Sem6">Sem6</option>
        <option value="Sem7">Sem7</option>
        <option value="Sem8">Sem8</option>
      </select>
      <label for="inputGroupSelect01">Semester</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md">
  <div class="form-floating">
    <select class="form-select" id="Sub1" required>
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option value="sub1">Applied Maths-1</option>
      <option value="sub2">Applied Physics-1</option>
      <option value="sub3">Applied Physics-2</option>

    </select>
    <label for="inputGroupSelect01">Subject Name</label>
```